# How to make dynamic 2d array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, arraylist, javafx

I've been looking around, but I can't find anything to solve my problem.

I have this method to create a board for my game:

```
public void createBoard(Canvas canvas) {
    ROWS_NUM = (int) canvas.getHeight() / rectangleSize;
    COLS_NUM = (int) canvas.getWidth() / rectangleSize;
    grid = new Cell[COLS_NUM][ROWS_NUM];

    for (int x = 0; x < COLS_NUM; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ROWS_NUM; y++) {
            grid[x][y] = new Cell();
            grid[x][y].setAndUpdateState(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is whenever I add a value thats greater than `ROWS_NUM` and `COLS_NUM` I get Array index out of bounds, as I should. I want to make the array dynamic, and I wonder how I should go about that. Would I have to convert the array to an ArrayList, or would a HashMap be better? And how would I do that, if I want both rows and columns to be dynamic?

Comment: An array is always fixed. To resize it, you need to reallocate it. If you want something dynamic, use a java.util container like List.

Comment: yes, using an ArrayList would be best, so basically, you would have Arraylist  of ArrayLists.

Comment: "And how would I do that, if I want both rows and columns to be dynamic?" <- An ArrayList already has a dynamic size. You can add and remove from it as you like and it will grow/shrink accordingly.

Comment: Depending on how often you resize your array you should think about what type of list you favor -  LinkedList or ArrayList. The former can be re-sized more efficiently but accessing its elements takes more time. The elements of the latter are accessed very quickly but changing it's size is more costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *ArrayList*, but to insert at any index without worrying about going out of bounds, you'd want to use nested *Map* with a special method for insertion or retrieval.

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Cell>> grid = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Cell>>();

for (int x = 0; x <= COLS_NUM; x++) {
    Map inner = new HashMap<Integer, Cell>();
    for (int y = 0; y < ROWS_NUM; y++) {
        inner.put(y, new Cell());
    }
    grid.put(x, inner);
}
```

Now you could create a method to set cells int the grid with any indices like this:

```
 public void setCell(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Cell>> grid, Cell newCell, int x, int y) {
    if (grid.containsKey(x)) {
        grid.get(x).put(y, newCell);
    } else {
        grid.put(x, (new HashMap<Integer, Cell>().put(y, newCell)));
    }
}
```

And a method for retrieving a cell:

```
     public Cell getCell(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Cell>> grid, int x, int y) {
     try {
         Cell found = grid.get(x).get(y);
         return found;
     } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

To make this useful, you'd want to create a custom class that manages these maps and the insertion / retrieval methods for you, along with other functions useful to your application.

Here's a simpler option using lists.  As mentioned above, this won't let you avoid the possibility of getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
int ROWS_NUM = (int) canvas.getHeight() / rectangleSize;
int COLS_NUM = (int) canvas.getWidth() / rectangleSize;

List<List<Cell>> array = new ArrayList<List<Cell>>();

for (int x = 0; x < COLS_NUM; x++) {
    List inner = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    for (int y = 0; y < ROWS_NUM; y++) {
        inner.add(new Cell());
    }
    array.add(inner);
}
```

You can still access specific cells (the equivalent of array[x][y] in the array this way:

```
// Find equivalent of arr[2][3]
Cell found = array.get(2).get(3);
```

However, because you specified that you want to be able to access cells with any index without getting an out of bounds exception, you could choose to implement it with Maps.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this answer. This looks extremely helpful! Thank you very much

Comment: How ever, I can't seem to get the something.get(x).get(y) to work, at least not when I tried with ArrayList. Does this only work with Map?

Comment: @r4tchet what error are you getting? It should work with nested lists or maps (maps with Integer keys)

Comment: If I do `public boolean isAlive(int x, int y){ List<Cell> cells = grid.get(x); cells.get(x).get(y); }`, it says _Cannot resolve method get(int)_. This is all new territory for me though, so it's probably a fault on my end

Comment: @r4tchet the problem is that you're calling **get** three times by instantiating  **cells**.  That would only work if you had **three** nested lists.  My proposed method was to just drill down to the value from the grid itself:  {  return grid.get(x).get(y).isAlive(); }

Comment: Ahhh okay! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't all that easy.

You can certainly represent your grid as a `List<List<Cell>>`.

```
 public Cell getCell(int x, int y) {
       return grid.get(x).get(y);
 }
```

However that doesn't give you a free pass to assign to any old number:

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.set(5,"Hello");
```

... will throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception too.

You can `list.add(string)` as many times as you like, and each time the list will grow. But you can't `set()` beyond its current size.

However if you know you want a cell object for every grid position, and you know that every time it grows it will grow by one, write your algorithm to use `add()` not `set()`, and this structure will work well.

---

Alternatively, as you suggest, a `HashMap<Coordinates, Cell>` *might* suit your needs.

You'll need a suitable `Coordinates` class, with a working `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementation. Then you could do:

```
   Map<Coordinates, Cell> grid = new HashMap<>();
   grid.put(new Coordinates(80, 100), new Cell());
```

This would work especially well if you want a "grid" that's sparsely populated but effectively unbounded.

There are plenty more approaches - including implementing your own array-reallocating algorithm (after all, that's what's inside an `ArrayList` -- find and study its source code, if you're curious).

---

You should probably also step back and ask *why* and *when* you need to change the size of the grid after initialising it. A fixed-size array of fixed-size arrays is a simple solution, and worth sticking with if it works most of the time. If the size only changes occasionally, maybe you'd be better off just creating a new grid and copying the old values into it whenever that happens.

```
  public void setCell(int x, int y, Cell cell) {
     if(x >= this.grid.length || y >= this.grid[0].length) {
          Cell[][] newGrid = createEmptyGrid(x,y);
          copyCells(this.grid,newGrid);
          this.grid = newGrid;
     }
     this.grid[x][y] = cell;
  }
```

`createEmptyGrid()` here needs to make a decision about the new size -- just big enough to accommodate `[x][y]`? Or bigger just-in-case? The right thing to do depends on your broader requirements.

Comment: I will try to wrap my head around this. Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

A better choice will be to use a Java **List** in order to implement required logic:

```
List<List<Cell>> grid = new ArrayList<>();

for (int x = 0; x < COLS_NUM; x++) {
    List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int y = 0; y < ROWS_NUM; y++) {
        cells.add(new Cell());
    }
    grid.add(cells);
}

public boolean isAlive(int x, int y) {
    List<Cell> cells = grid.get(x);
    Cell cell = cells.get(y);        
    return cell != null && cell.getState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ArayList (ArrayList can change it's size dynamicly)

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grid= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```